# Splitting arrays in imported file with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

This is my first question here :)

I have imported a csv file with np.loadtxt

```
infile = np.loadtxt("glob_temp_anom_1.csv", dtype="int, float", delimiter=",", usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
```

And got the following variable

```
[array([2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,
   2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,
   2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015,
   2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015,
   2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014,
   2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014,
   2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2013, 2013,
   2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013,
   2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012,
   2012]), array([0.7895, 0.81  , 0.7504, 0.93  , 0.7292, 0.89  , 0.8767, 0.87  ,
   0.8998, 0.98  , 0.8687, 0.83  , 0.9006, 0.76  , 0.8738, 0.93  ,
   1.0733, 1.09  , 1.2245, 1.3   , 1.1921, 1.35  , 1.0569, 1.17  ,
   1.1219, 1.11  , 0.9655, 1.04  , 0.9913, 1.06  , 0.926 , 0.81  ,
   0.8746, 0.78  , 0.8072, 0.71  , 0.8835, 0.78  , 0.8584, 0.78  ,
   0.7741, 0.74  , 0.8969, 0.9   , 0.8843, 0.86  , 0.8141, 0.81  ,
   0.8308, 0.79  , 0.6895, 0.67  , 0.7851, 0.85  , 0.7872, 0.9   ,
   0.7986, 0.82  , 0.6988, 0.57  , 0.7623, 0.66  , 0.7938, 0.87  ,
   0.8006, 0.78  , 0.7695, 0.77  , 0.48  , 0.51  , 0.6936, 0.73  ,
   0.6981, 0.67  , 0.8293, 0.81  , 0.6787, 0.69  , 0.6857, 0.78  ,
   0.6605, 0.66  , 0.6662, 0.59  , 0.6838, 0.65  , 0.7141, 0.61  ,
   0.561 , 0.52  , 0.6139, 0.66  , 0.6357, 0.55  , 0.5873, 0.68  ,
   0.4655, 0.53  , 0.7087, 0.75  ])]
```

I want to plot the arrays where the first array (years, [0] is 2017) is x-axis and the floats in second array is y-axis.

I can't seem to split the arrays in `infile` variable into two variables `xaxis` and `yaxis` to get the axis in *plt.plot* to be correct.

Is there a easier way to plot the arrays without splitting the variable `infile`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since index 0 of your data array refers to the x-data and index 1 refers to the y-data, you can plot the simply like (assuming `data` is your data array):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data[0], data[1])
plt.show()
```